# Can I "link" my Lambda's temp directory to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am currently using FFMPEG to generate files in a lambda. Unfortunately the output options are pretty limited in terms of "to disk" or SFTP. I am trying to avoid making an FTP server for this.

Is there any way to listen to writes onto the `/tmp` dir and forward them over to an S3 file instead? If there's no AWS feature for swapping out what counts as the temporary dir, I am thinking I might be able to split the output file into chunks and "listen" for each chunk completing in some way by "watching" the folder.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

An AWS Lambda function is provided 512MB of disk space in `/tmp/`. Any communication with Amazon S3 would need to be done via the code in the Lambda function..